# Shuffle randomly values in array - python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have the following array

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1]
```

And I want to know how I can shuffle any two values *randomly* within an array that isn't either the first or last value. Some examples of the desired results below:

```
Output = 

[1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]

[1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

[1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 1]
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
import random
from random import shuffle

a = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1]
hold = a[1:-1]
random.shuffle(hold)
shuffled_list = [a[0]] + hold + [a[-1]]
shuffled_list
>> 
Out[87]:
[1, 5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1]
```